# How to calculate the number of neighbors of a string with exact and at most d mismatches?

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, combinations, enumeration

Given a string, and a set of four alphabets (A, B, C, D) for generating strings of length n. I need a generalized mathematical formula to calculate the number of neighbors for any string of length *n* with at most *d* mismatches, and the number of neighbors with exactly d mismatches.

**For example:** Given a string=”**AAA**” and *d*=3

- We have 9 Strings with **exactly** *d*=1

```
    BAA  
    CAA  
    DAA  
    ABA  
    ACA  
    ADA  
    AAB   
    AAC   
    AAD
```

- We have 27 Strings with **exactly** *d*=2

```
BBA   BCA   BDA   
BAB   BAC   BAD
CBA   CCA   CDA   
CAB   CAC   CAD
DBA   DCA   DDA   
DAB   DAC   DAD
ABB   ABC   ABD
ACB   ACC   ACD
ADB   ADC   ADD
```

- We have 27 Strings with **exactly** *d*=3

```
BBB   CBB   DBB   
BCB   CCB   DCB
BDB   CDB   DDB   
BBC   CBC   DBC
BCC   CCC   DCC    
BDC   CDC   DDC   
BBD   CBD   DBD    
BCD   CCD   DCD   
BDD   CDD   DDD
```

- Number of Strings with **at most** *d*=3 are 9+27+27=63 strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider a string of size `n`.
We want to know how many 'neighbors' this string has, with a distance `d`. The first thing we remark, with your definition of 'distance', is that it means that we must choose `d` characters among the `n` of the string and modify them. So there are `n choose d` possible combinations of charactersto modify.
Each of these can be modified in `3` different manners (since the size of the alphabet is `4`.
So ultimately, we have:

- `n choose d` possible combinations of characters that will be modified
- `d` characters will be modified, and each of them can be modified in `3`different manners.

So the formula is ultimately `(s - 1) ^ d * (n choose d)`, where `s` is the size of the alphabet (here `4`). I let you verify that it fits the first examples you provided.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I think this formula `(s - 1) * d * (n choose d)` should be                `(s - 1) ^ d * (n choose d)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try it out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int n = 3; int d = 2;
string s = "AAA";
    
int counter(string curr, int index, int currd){
    if(currd == 0 || index == n){
        cout<<curr<<s.substr(index, n - index)<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    int ans = 0;
    for(char c = 'A'; c < 'E'; c++){
        if(c != s[index]){
            ans += counter(curr + c, index + 1, currd - 1);
        }
        else{
            ans += counter(curr + c, index + 1, currd);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

int main(){
    cout<<"answer = "<<counter("", 0, d) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Appreciated, this code helps clearly and fast verifying the calculations.  Also, the code is clear.